Loop through sheets, copy range, paste to different workbook
I have two excel workbooks with numerous tabs, but they are the same between the two excel files, and in the same order.  This is for financial reporting where I get monthly updates (actuals) and then use that to update projections.  I can't simply merge or concatenate dataframes, I need to copy the same range (eg this month's update) and overwrite the projected monthly data.
I have the code below that lets me copy a range from the source and paste into the destination. I'd like something cleaner, but this has been tested and works.  The issue here is that I have explicitly named a worksheet for the code to work.
How can I get python to loop through the process of copying  a range from sheet 1 (source excel file) and paste to sheet 1 of the destination file and then move to all subsequent sheets?
import openpyxl
#File to be copied
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'C:\Users\source.xlsx') 
sheet = wb["Combined Total by Month"]

#File to be pasted into
template = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'C:\Users\destination.xlsx')
temp_sheet = template["Combined Total by Month"] 

#Copy range of cells as a nested list
#Takes: start cell, end cell, and sheet you want to copy from.
def copyRange(startCol, startRow, endCol, endRow, sheet):
    rangeSelected = []
    #Loops through selected Rows
    for i in range(startRow,endRow + 1,1):
        #Appends the row to a RowSelected list
        rowSelected = []
        for j in range(startCol,endCol+1,1):
            rowSelected.append(sheet.cell(row = i, column = j).value)
        #Adds the RowSelected List and nests inside the rangeSelected
        rangeSelected.append(rowSelected)

    return rangeSelected

#Paste range
#Paste data from copyRange into template sheet
def pasteRange(startCol, startRow, endCol, endRow, sheetReceiving,copiedData):
    countRow = 0
    for i in range(startRow,endRow+1,1):
        countCol = 0
        for j in range(startCol,endCol+1,1):
            sheetReceiving.cell(row = i, column = j).value = copiedData[countRow][countCol]
            countCol += 1
        countRow += 1
def createData():
    selectedRange = copyRange(17,11,19,29,sheet) 
    pastingRange = pasteRange(16,11,18,29,temp_sheet,selectedRange) 
template.save("output.xlsx")


For your specific question I think you are just asking to loop the worksheet in the workbook (wb) so you can call the copy and paste functions using each worksheet in the workbook.
There are two main options to do this;

wb.worksheets
wb.sheetnames

The first is the list of actual worksheet objects in the workbook, whereas the second is a list of worksheet names.
The worksheet objects are are obviously particular to the workbook the list list is taken from.
I've suggested using names here as

they can then be used by either source or destination workbook to obtain the correct worksheet object
if you have Sheets you don't want to copy you can drop them based on name.
You are absolutely sure that you are using the same sheet in both workbooks
However it would still be valid to say loop the worksheets and then obtain the title of the current worksheet to use to reference the worksheet in the other workbook, e.g.

for worksheet in wb.worksheets:
    # worksheet is the worksheet object of the source workbook
    print(worksheet['A1'].value)
    # Create the destination worksheet from the source worksheet name
    template_ws = template[worksheet.title]
    print(template_ws['A1'].value)

As mentioned in the other answer you may use the index of the sheet in either list if they are as you indicated in the same order (not necessary guaranteed in Excel but should be the case).
Using the sheet_name you can check it fits a criteria if needed, e.g. includes the word 'Total' or 'Month' or 'Combined Total' etc
i.e.
...
def createData():
    for sheet_name in wb.sheetnames:
        if <sheet_name fits criteria>:
            selectedRange = copyRange(17,11,19,29,sheet_name)
            pastingRange = pasteRange(16,11,18,29,sheet_name,selectedRange)

Then create the worksheet object using the appropriate workbook object in the function if the two are using different workbooks.
e.g.
def copyRange(startCol, startRow, endCol, endRow, sheetn):
    sheet = wb[sheetn]
    rangeSelected = []
    ...

and
def pasteRange(startCol, startRow, endCol, endRow, sheetn, copiedData):
    sheetReceiving = template[sheetn]
    countRow = 0
    ...

However your code seems to be unnecessarily complex you should be able to just copy and paste in the one operation.
Read the cell in the range and copy to the same cell in the other workbook Sheet offset by one column.
import openpyxl
#File to be copied
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('source.xlsx')

#File to be pasted into
template = openpyxl.load_workbook('destination.xlsx')


def copy_paste(startCol,startRow,endCol,endRow):
    for sheet_name in wb.sheetnames:

        for row in wb[sheet_name].iter_rows(min_row=startRow,min_col=startCol,max_row=endRow,max_col=endCol):
            for cell in row:
                cell_coord = cell.coordinate
                ### Copy Source workbook cell value to the same cell (offset by one column) in the destination workbook
                ### So value in 'Q11' is copied to 'P11' etc
                template[sheet_name].cell(row=cell.row, column=cell.column-1).value = cell.value


copy_paste(17,11,19,29)
template.save("output.xlsx")


You can get them by index with:
ws = wb.worksheets[0] 
ts = template.worksheets[0]

where 0 is the first sheet, 1 is second sheet and so on if the order of the sheets correlates with each other on both workbooks, or you know what worksheets correspond to each other.
